# How to pass array to API for response in android?

Tags: android, web-services, api, arraylist, request

I have one api. In that i have to pass some parameters, some parameters among them i have to pass them like array arraylist. My example Request ?Url is as below:

**http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/order.php?customer_id=3&address_id=31&products%5B0%5D%5BproductName%5D=rt&products%5B0%5D%5Bproduct_id%5D=41&products%5B0%5D%5Bquantity%5D=2&products%5B0%5D%5Bunit%5D=1&products%5B0%5D%5BunitPrice%5D=400**
[MY API request with parameters](http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/order.php?customer_id=3&address_id=31&products%5B0%5D%5BproductName%5D=rt&products%5B0%5D%5Bproduct_id%5D=41&products%5B0%5D%5Bquantity%5D=2&products%5B0%5D%5Bunit%5D=1&products%5B0%5D%5BunitPrice%5D=400)

I havej no idea how to build; this kind if request url... Can anyone suggest me for it what should i do..Or any help code?

Answer (score 1):

```
private String httpGetRequest() throws Exception
    {
        String receiveStr = "";
        String urlRequest = urlString;

        DefaultHttpClient client = null;

        HttpResponse execute;

            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlRequest);
            execute = client.execute(httpGet);

        InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        client = null;
        receiveStr = stringBuffer.toString();
        return receiveStr;
    }
```

Then for parse JSON you can use usefull GSON library.

You must create variable urlString in code : 
String urlString = "http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/order.php?customer_id=3&address_id=31&products%5B0%5D%5BproductName%5D=rt&products%5B0%5D%5Bproduct_id%5D=41&products%5B0%5D%5Bquantity%5D=2&products%5B0%5D%5Bunit%5D=1&products%5B0%5D%5BunitPrice%5D=400"
by your current Get Http parametrs: customer_id, address_id, etc
This code above return to you String variable like this: "{"status":"Sucess","order_id":1070,"order_product_id":[1325],"complete_order_time":["1"],"product_id":["41"],"payee_key":["2511131I093517"]}"
Then you must parse it JSON string variable. Very usefull library for parse JSON string is GSON library . Read this https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: can't getting you..what you have replied...? i want to know how to pass an arrayList to my request to api as i have asked and give also an example.